# setRetainInstance does not work for all UI elements?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I'm using the Sherlock ActionBar library and use tabs and fragments for the main layout of my app. One of the fragments starts an AsyncTask, now when the orientation of the device changes I want the task to just continue running. So i started using the setRetainInstance(true) method on the fragment. Everything works fine, when I switch orientation the task just continues running as expected and updates the ListView correctly.

But my layout also has some buttons which I disable and enable when running the task.
The problem is that when the device switches orientation the ListView and EditText in my layout are getting saved but my buttons are not! And because I use the setRetainInstance(true) I can't use the Bundle savedInstanceState method it will always return null.

So how can iIsave the complete fragment UI and Task? And why does setRetainInstace not save buttons?

Comment: I'm also having an issue with the text of a TextView not being saved and recreated as expected. Did you find any more information on this?

Comment: I ended up saving the states on my own, using setRetainInstance(true) and some custom variables to save the states in.

Comment: Thanks, seems I'll do it that way as well :/